# Concrete5 Website breaking in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, concrete5

I'm using the developer tab with IE and my concrete 5 website [peacefulschools.com](http://peacefulschools.com) is not loading all of the way when I change Document Mode to any other mode besides "standard". The following are the javascript errors below. I haven't looked too deeply into them as there are other Concrete 5 users that are reporting a similar error. Can you see the issue? I'm not really sure how to use IE developer tools well!

> HTML1416: Unexpected character in comment end. Expected "-->". 
>   peacefulschools.com, line 55 character 6 SEC7115: :visited and :link
>   styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to
>   :visited.  peacefulschools.com 
>   Invalid App Id: Must be a number or
>   numeric string representing the application id.  FB.getLoginStatus()
>   called before calling FB.init().  HTML1500: Tag cannot be
>   self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag.  peacefulschools.com, line
>   191 character 3 HTML1506: Unexpected token.  peacefulschools.com, line
>   227 character 2

Comment: What version of Concrete are you running?

Comment: 5.6.2.1 but we have seen others have the same issue on all versions.

Comment: Just saw the same thing when I used IE last night.  I can login fine, but I lose the Editing Bar atogether..

Comment: Did someone add a Facebook integration?  It looks like something is broken with FB getloginStatus.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to disable it tomorrow and see if that does it